# 2007 Access if else statement that returns a text string

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, if-statement

I have a access 2007 report for which one of the fields returns a numerical value of $0 if there no dollar amount associated with the project listed, else it returns a dollar amount greater than $0.

What I want to do is build the report so that if the field value = $0, I want it to read "TBD" (without the quotes) else, I want it to return the dollar amount.

Two part question--first, what Sub class would I write the code under?

And, how would I go about writing the if else statement?

Here is what I came up so far and it doesn't do anything (no errors, just returns the report with the $0's printed where no dollar amount is available).

```
Private Sub Cost_AfterUpdate()
If ([YearofExpenditureCost] >= 0) Then
Me.Cost = "TBD"
Else: Me.Cost = [YearofExpenditureCost]
End If
```

Where the [Cost] is the name of the text box containing the ControlSource value of [YearofExpenditureCost].

Many thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an immediate If as the Control Source of a textbox on the report. Ensure that the testbox has a name other than any of the fields in the recordsource:

```
=IIF(YearofExpenditureCost=0, "TBD",YearofExpenditureCost)
```

Comment: I tried this and it returns a #Name? for all fields in the report.  No other fields in the recordsource have the same name.

Comment: This is likely to be a space or misspelling or such. Here are some suggestions on tracking down the error: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/i-see-name-displayed-in-a-control-HA001181447.aspx

Comment: No, I quadruple checked syntax errors and its still giving me the same thing. This is how I wrote it: =If([YearofExpenditureCost]=0,"TBD",[YearofExpenditureCost])

Comment: You are short one i ( I I F )  iif

Comment: Lol--sorry, I thought that was a typo!  Why the extra "I"?

Comment: Thanks--looked it up because I was curious...learned something new! :)

Answer (score 1):

The format property of the form has four parts (from Access help):

```
  First   The format for positive numbers. 
  Second  The format for negative numbers. 
  Third   The format for zero values. 
  Fourth  The format for Null values.
```

Thus, if you set the format property to `;;"TBD";` it should display the value or "TDB" if it's zero -- there is no code required for this, just setting a property of the control on the report.

Comment: So this would be written in the control source property or somewhere else?  Also, there would be no =iif() statement involved?  Because I just set the control source to =;;"TBD"; and also just ;;"TBD"; and it didn't work.

Comment: This would be the .Format property of the control, which is what I said in the first sentence.